# Definition of component for a digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

I could find this in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory)

> **Component**: *A connected component of a graph is a maximal connected subgraph. The term is also used for maximal subgraphs or subsets of a graph's vertices that have some higher order of connectivity, including biconnected components, triconnected components, and strongly connected components.*

which I haven't yet understoond in a directed graph. I am studying the Handbook of Graph Theory by Gross et all. You may use the following example for demonstrations. So

**What is the definition of component for a digraph?**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there are two concepts of "connected" for a digraph. "Weakly connected" means connected as a graph (ignoring the direction of all the edges), "strongly connected" means having a path between any two points. Similarly there is a distinction between strongly connected components and weakly connected components. So the bare terms "connected" and "component" are ambiguous for a digraph. Maybe the context helps.

Comment: @almagest Well written, the context is cut-vertex for a digraph. This is for an undirected graph: *"Cut-vertex is a vertex the removal of which increases the number of components"*. The choice of connectness affects the component, weakly-connected component or strongly-connected component? I am studying the Handbook of Graph Theory by Gross et all.

Comment: I see that there are some definitions on page 165. Do they help?

Comment: @almagest yes and in the [digraph example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IcBIV.png): the weakly-connected components have all edges and vertices while the strongly-connected components do not have the edges and the vertices. Here the removal of the vertex cut {1,2} does not increase the number of components so is definition wrong of vertex-cut for digraph that its removal increases the number of components or is the definition of connectedness wrong? Weakly st-connected components (here weakly AB-connected components are A-1-B and A-1-B while removal leaves no component)? Vertex cut for digraph?

Comment: @almagest I moved the vertex-cut issue for digraphs to [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790189/definition-of-vertex-cut-for-digraph), it is related to the components if the definition is analogous with undirected graphs.

Answer (score 1):

A *connected component* is usually only defined on undirected graphs. (see below). For the more general digraphs we use the concept of *strongly connected components* (see below) which generalize the notion of *connected components* to directed graphs. Sometimes we also talk about *weak connectedness* which is just the (undirected) connectedness if when we consider the graph where we replace the directed edges with undirected ones.

> In graph theory, a connected component (or just component) of an undirected graph is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph.

This means the *subgraph* we are talking about does have to meet following criterion:

- For any two vertices in this subgraph there is a path that begins with one and ends in the other.

The second part is merely a corollary.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29

For digraphs we talk about *strongly connected components*:

> A directed graph is called strongly connected if there is a path in each direction between each pair of vertices of the graph. In a directed graph G that may not itself be strongly connected, a pair of vertices u and v are said to be strongly connected to each other if there is a path in each direction between them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

Comment: Can you clarify, demonstrate *"which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph."*? I find this part hard reading.

Comment: Does this *"which"* refers to any vertex in the subgraph? I really need some example on this, why the last part with *", which --"*?

Comment: The *which*'s refer to the *subgraph*, I updated my answer.

Comment: How is the first definition different without the last part in the form *"a connected component (or just component) of an undirected graph is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths"*? Do you mean the last part makes trivial cycles possible (path from the same vertex to the same vertex)?

Comment: @hhh This is often already excluded in the definition of a *graph*. But it is just a detail that does not matter as long you know which context you are in.