# Definition of vertex-cut for digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

I am trying to understand vertex cut for digraph. I could find this for graphs

> *Vertex cut is a vertex whose removal increases the number of components in a graph.* (D67, Handbook of Graph Theory by Gross)

and components for digraphs defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790107/definition-of-component-for-a-digraph). I am interested in st-connectivity so if the digraph definition is analogous with the undirected definition, then the removal of the cut should increase the number of st-connected components. So

**What is the definition of vertex-cut for digraph?**

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the digraph as an undirected graph with the cut-vertex set definition such that

> *Cut-vertex set of a digraph is a vertex set whose removal increases the number of weakly-connected components.*

where the weak connectness. This statement does not work in the case of strong connectness: consider the example on page 165 of the book and remove the vertex set {y,w} in which case the number of components does not increase with strongly connected components.